# Can enjoy or will enjoy

Tags: word-choice

In the marketing copy for a cookbook, should "can" or "will" be used before enjoy:

> The Blood Type Cookbook: Easy, Healthy and Delicious Recipes for the Whole Family shows you how to quickly prepare scrumptious meals that all family members, regardless of blood type, **can enjoy**. Your family will rush to the table for meals bursting with flavor and supercharged with foods approved for the blood type dietary guidelines. Includes 50+ mouthwatering, mix-and-match recipes for breakfast, lunch, dinner and dessert, Prep Tips and a Grocery Shopping List.

Comment: either *can* or *will* can function in this ad copy -- at least in AmE. Each has a slightly different sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Can** should probably be used. Saying "**can** enjoy" allows for the possibility of enjoyment. It's implied that there are meals that certain family members **cannot** enjoy, due to blood-related concerns; even if the family member enjoys the taste, they will not enjoy the medical effect that the meal has on their blood/condition. Ultimately, such a meal would not be enjoyable.

Saying "**will** enjoy" suggests that the Cookbook's author knows for a fact that the family members of the reader will enjoy the aforementioned scrumptious meals, regardless of how well it is cooked or said family members' taste preferences.

I hope no cookbook I buy in the store ever has such knowledge of my personal tastes.

Comment: That having been said, the claim accompanying 'will' is often used in advertising, and is never taken to be gospel, but perceived as non-sinister over-egging.

Comment: I agree and am glad to have had my intuition supported by your excellent response. And I'm a copywriter of integrity and hate the way most marketing copy is shoved at people thank you!